# Send beat logs from client to ELK server

Tags: elasticsearch

I have three machines
1. RedHAT (ELK Server)
2. MS Server 2012 R2
3. Ubuntu

I have setup ELK on the REDHAT server. Then I have set up topbeat and packetbeat in all machines. I have changed the topbeat.yml and packet.yml in all machines so as to send the logs to ELK server via elasticsearch. However, I can only read data from my local ELK server but cant read any data from other Servers

Any ways to resolve it?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

make sure that you have changed the elasticsearch.yml file in your redhat server and it accepts traffic from outside networks . Usually this defaults to localhost.

```
network.host: 0.0.0.0 //This will let your server listen from all of the servers which are destined towards your elasticsearch server
```

and properly add the ip address of elasticsearch server in hosts array of output in topbeat.yml and packetbeat.yml

```
elasticsearch:
       hosts: ["localhost:9200"] //CHANGE THE LOCALHOST AND PORT ACCORDINGLY
```